# how to chose right version of mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Upgrading the database version needs intensive testing. 
Is it better to upgrade to latest version of MySQL workbench?
If we are installing previous versions of MySQL database, Is there any certification matrix to know all the corresponding version of MySQL workbench or  what minimum version it can work with?

Answer (score 0):

Mysql-Workbench using libmysql.dll. You must update this dll from your mysql\lib folder. So a lot function working same as before.